# How table storage loops works?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Does anyone knows how data is beeing retrived from table storage?

```
var result = ctx.CreateQuery<Contact>("Contacts")
                    .Where(x => x.PartitionKey == "key")
                    .Take(50)
                    .AsTableServiceQuery<Contact>().Execute();
foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.FirstName);
}
```

Does it get all items from storage and than loops through them or it get each item separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following links.

This one talks about the basics of table storage - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796231.aspx

This one covers more than you are asking about, but there are some How To code examples that might be useful for querying table storage - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/

I also recommend this video from the PDC. It's a deep dive into tables and queues in Azure. - http://www.microsoftpdc.com/2009/svc09

Answer (score 0):

You could have checked this using Fiddler. Table service is a REST Service, the CreateQuery() method creates REST Query, executes a HTTP REST Call, then parses the result, which is a XML containing all the entities in the result for the query (limit to 1000 and including continuation tokens if result is more than 1000). All the items are in the result XML, there is no point for querieng every single item from the result.